# Convert long NSString to NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I am unable to reliably convert longer `NSString` to `NSNumber`.  Specifically, I am converting `MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID` as a string to a `NSNumber`  Sometimes it works, usually it doesn't.

Conversion code:

```
 NSString *keke = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"next"];
 NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
 NSNumber *persistentIDasNumber = [f numberFromString:keke];
```

Here is an example of a successful string to number conversion:

```
String: 3813955856659208324
Number: 3813955856659208324
```

And here is an unsuccessful conversion:

```
String: 12790162104953153719 
Number:1.279016210495315e+19
```

It's close but what is happening at the end?  Is it too large?

Comment: Does it have to be NSNumber? or can it be an int or unsigned int or a float?

Comment: I think it has to be an `NSNumber` as the media player function takes that.  However if you can post integer conversions I can try those in the media player.

Comment: well to do int would be `NSString *string = @"5";
int value = [string intValue];`

Comment: Unfortunate it wont take the int, it says `Implicit conversion of int to id is not allowed with ARC`

Comment: @Scott, yes possible, but if you look at his code example, you see that he used that answer and now he is trying to see why that answer doesn't work for him. John, have you tried putting in the number that gets output? the 1.279016210495315e+19 is correct decimal notation for a number that long.

Comment: I set a breakpoint and am observing the values in x-code, ill try NSLog.  Scott, i've tried the solutions in that link. CaptJak, im not sure how it's sending the number to the function - whenever x-code outputs it without decimals the function works.

Comment: `NSLog:1.429365487195657e+19`..is it possible this is how its actually being sent and the function isn't reading the notation properly?  I have no idea whats going on and why it's only for some numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the largest integer number that can be processed with NSNumberFormatter is long long, which is 9223372036854775807. Anything beyond that will lose precision and not come out as you put it in.

Instead use NSDecimalNumber, a concrete subclass of NSNumber. And it can even parse strings itself:

```
NSDecimalNumber *dn=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithString:@"12790162104953153719"];
NSLog(@"dn: %@",dn);
```

NSDecimalNumber can handle up to 38 digit long decimal numbers before it loses precision.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you do it:

```
unsigned long long number = [[jsonArray objectForKey:@"next"] longLongValue];
    NSNumber * numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:number];
```

Comment: Thanks but its not matching, `string:15295462469298033064` gives me `numberValue:9223372036854775807`

Comment: It is working in many more cases though!  any idea how to expand the capability so I can be 100% sure of those instances where the song has a longer ID such as above?

Comment: this is happenign because you are hitting the limit for long long too...so you need the next big type...I am looking for it

Comment: Ah wow I never realized how large these numbers would end up getting, m nowhere near a good developer but i will look too.  if it helps, here is another string i found that didn't work `9223372036854775807`